# Android SimpleCursorAdapter ListView Error

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I've been messing with SimpleCursorAdapter and Listview and getting varied results. At first I was getting some results on my listview however the layout wasn't good so I decided to mend this. However that has seemed to ruin everything now the APP keeps crashing with a nullpointer exception type error and I can't seem to figure out.

My XML for the listview

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1" >





        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

My activity class with ListActivity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.playerdata);
    //list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    mDbHelper = new PlayerDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    fillData();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

 private void fillData() {
    Cursor players = mDbHelper.fetchAllPlayers();
    startManagingCursor(players);

    // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
    String[] from = new String[]{PlayerDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE,PlayerDbAdapter.KEY_BODY};


    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.playerPosition,R.id.playerName};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter playerlist = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.playerinfo , players, from, to);
    setListAdapter(playerlist);
}
```

LogCat

```
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{your.dissertation.project/your.dissertation.project.PlayersActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1544)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.app.ListActivity.ensureList(ListActivity.java:312)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.app.ListActivity.getListView(ListActivity.java:297)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at your.dissertation.project.PlayersActivity.<init>(PlayersActivity.java:27)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1536)
04-15 20:09:07.326: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  ... 11 more
```

**My Cursor class**

```
 public Cursor fetchAllPlayers()
  {
    return this.mDb.query("players", new String[] { "_id", "Player_Name", "Player_Position" }, null, null, null, null, null);
  }
```

Comment: Post the entire logcat please.

Comment: Updated it with entire logcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but I see a couple of problems:

1. startManagingCursor is deprecated. You should use a CursorLoader instead. This is documented in the Android training class [Loading Data in the Background](http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html). This isn't causing your RuntimeException, but it's bad programming practice.
2. The setup of your ListView and SimpleCursorAdapter needs work. You've made a mistake which is quite common with people using SimpleCursorAdapter. The parameters to the constructor are

```
SimpleCursorAdapter(Context, item_layout_file, Cursor, from_columns, to_fields)
```

where

- **Context** is a Context object
- **item_layout_file** is a layout.xml file that contains the layout of *one item or line* of your listview. In your case, this layout file would contain a TextView (or two?), and *not* the ListView. You're creating an object that's bound to the ListView, not the ListView itself.
- **Cursor** is the Cursor containing data
- **from_columns** is a string array containing column names
- **to_fields** is an integer array containing the resource IDs of view objects in the item layout file.

In addition, there are these requirements:

- the number of elements in **from_columns** must be the same as the number of elements in **to_fields**. **I suspect that this is causing the error**.
- The **Cursor** must contain the column named "_ID".

However, **from_columns** doesn't have to contain all the columns in the Cursor.

Comment: What you said made alot of sense, I'm goign to have another crack at it. Thanks very much. However my development target is 9 and I notice CursorLoader was implemented in 11? Thanks anyway I think i'll stick with Simple for now. Will keep you updated with progress.

Comment: So I manged to rectify the from_column & to_field irregularities also created a new xml file with 2 text views which I linked to the to_feild however I'm still getting the nullexception error. Maybe its to do with the last bullet point which I don't really understand what you meant by an ID column. Updated code with my cursor class, it has ID column.

Answer (score 0):

Change
`String[] from = new String[]{PlayerDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE,PlayerDbAdapter.KEY_BODY};`

to

```
String[] from = new String[]{PlayerDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};
```

Comment: I rectified the to_feild to have an extra column as I needed both. Still having the same problem.

Comment: Repost your code you instantiate SimpleCursorAdapter wrongly.

Comment: Updated with new adapter code. Still getting nullpointexeption error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListView` should have an id `android:id="@android:id/list"` not `android:id="@+id/list"`

Comment: But if I do this how do I call it on the SimpleCursorAdapter? As it wont recognise list anymore.

Comment: Are you refering to this line `list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list)`?

It should be `list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list)`